# Complex scalar theory: annihilation and creation operators give wrong commutators with Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, klein-gordon-equation

The theory of a real (hermitian) scalar field can be found in many books and everywhere online. On the other hand, if we take the field non-hermitian, then I can only find notes on path integrals. I can't find anything about canonical commutations, so I tried to derive it myself. The thing is, I find a wrong commutator with the Hamiltonian, and I can't spot my mistake. I'd find it really helpful if somebody has anything to say about this.

I will probably miss some numerical factors and I might misplace some daggers/signs along this post, but these issues are not important right now. I apologise if there are some minor mistakes, please don't mind them. On the other hand, if there is any major mistake, please *mind* it and tell me :)

First step: the fields are $\phi(x)$, $\phi^\dagger(x)$, $\pi(x)$ and $\pi^\dagger(x)$. These commute as follow
$$
[\phi,\phi^\dagger]=[\pi,\pi^\dagger]=[\phi,\pi^\dagger]=0\\
[\phi,\pi]=[\phi^\dagger,\pi^\dagger]=i\delta(\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol y)
$$
(we obviously take the fields at equal times)

Second step: from KG equation, we solve for $\phi$
$$
\phi(x)=\int\frac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol k}{2\omega(\boldsymbol k)}\ \mathrm e^{-ikx}a(\boldsymbol k)+\mathrm e^{+ikx}b^\dagger(\boldsymbol k)
$$
and similar equations for the other fields. Inverting these, we find
$$
a(\boldsymbol k)=\int \mathrm d\boldsymbol x\ \mathrm e^{ikx} \left[\omega(\boldsymbol k)\phi(x)+i\pi^\dagger(x)\right]
$$
and similar equations for $b(\boldsymbol k)$.

Third step: write the hamiltonian as
$$
H=\int\frac{\mathrm d \boldsymbol k}{2\omega(\boldsymbol k)} \frac{1}{2}\omega(\boldsymbol k)\left[ a^\dagger(\boldsymbol k) a(\boldsymbol k)+b^\dagger(\boldsymbol k) b(\boldsymbol k)\right]
$$

The problem comes with the next (and final) step: if I work out the commutator of $a$ and $b$ with $H$, I get an unexpected result. For example,
$$
[H,a(\boldsymbol k)]=-\frac{1}{2}\omega(\boldsymbol k)\left[a(\boldsymbol k)+b(\boldsymbol k)\right]
$$
(I was expecting something like $[H,a]=-\omega a$; note that this would we had if $a=b$, i.e., the field was hermitian)

From this, we can see that $a$ can **not** be used as an annihilation operator, because if $|E\rangle$ is an state with energy $E$, then $a(\boldsymbol k)|E\rangle$ will **not** be another eigenstate with energy $E-\omega(\boldsymbol k)$; to see this, note that

$$
Ha(\boldsymbol k)|E\rangle=\big(a(\boldsymbol k)H+[H,a(\boldsymbol k)]\big)|E\rangle=\big(a(\boldsymbol k)E-\frac{1}{2}\omega(\boldsymbol k)\left[a(\boldsymbol k)+b(\boldsymbol k)\right]\big)|E\rangle
$$

If the field $\phi$ was hermitian, then $a=b$ so that the last equality would read $Ha|E\rangle=(E-\omega)a|E\rangle$, so $a$ *would* be an annihilation operator. On the other hand, if $a\neq b$, then nor $a$ nor $b$ decrese the energy of eigenstates. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly obtain your commutation relation for $[H, a]$. $a$ commutes with both $b^{\dagger}$ and $b$, so there could be no $b$ term there.

Comment: I thought that $[a(\boldsymbol k),b^\dagger(\boldsymbol q)]=2\omega(\boldsymbol k)\delta(\boldsymbol k-\boldsymbol q)$, but now I realise this is probably wrong. I'll check my calculations...

Comment: Well... let's say $[a(\boldsymbol k),b^\dagger(\boldsymbol q)]=0$. Then if $\phi$ is hermitian, then $a=b$. From this we get $[a(\boldsymbol k),a^\dagger(\boldsymbol q)]=0$, which is clearly wrong...

Comment: I don't get the $a = b$ part. How does it follow from $[a, b^{\dagger}] = 0$ ?

Comment: $a^*$ and $b^*$ create orthogonal states, since the single particle Hilbert space is doubled in a complexified theory and $a$ refers to, say, the first direct summand, while $b$ to the other, which are clearly orthogonal as such.

Comment: I checked my calculations and $[a,b^\dagger]=0$ indeed. You are right, there goes my mistake. Thankyou very much (congrats on spotting it so fast, that was surprising)

Comment: Nervermiind the $a=b$ part. I was thinking out loud... Anyway, why don't you write this as an actual answer so I can upvote it? cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct commutation relations for creation/annihilation operators are the following:

$$ [a(k), a^{\dagger} (k')] = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)} (k - k') $$
$$ [b(k), b^{\dagger} (k')] = (2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)} (k - k') $$

Everything else commutes, including $[a, b^{\dagger}]$.

From this, it is clear that $[H, a]$ can not depend on $b$.